# Getting error- GET http://localhost:8080/hello/variable/user net::ERR_FAILED on running Angular+Spring Boot application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

Getting below error when running the Angular+Spring boot application in localhost by disabling csrf() and enabling OPTION requests

Error- Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/hello/variable/paraan' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET http://localhost:8080/hello/variable/user net::ERR_FAILED   zone-evergreen.js:2845

Angular
welcome-data.service.ts

```
executeHelloWorldBeanServicePathVarible(name)
  {
    let basicAuthHeaderString=this.createBasicAuthenticationHttpHeader();
    let headers=new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization:basicAuthHeaderString
    })
   
    return this.http.get<helloWorldBean>
    (`http://localhost:8080/hello/variable/${name}`,
    {headers});
  }

  createBasicAuthenticationHttpHeader(){
    let username='user'
    let password='dummy'
    
    let basicAuthHeaderString='Basic' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password);
    
    return basicAuthHeaderString;
    
      }
```

SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth.java

```
package com.practice.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.basic.auth;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
  public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
  
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  
  http
  .csrf().disable()
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
  .anyRequest().authenticated() 
  .and() 
  //.formLogin().and() 
  .httpBasic(); 
  }
  
  }
```

Edited the SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth.java

```
package com.practice.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.basic.auth;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()   
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            //.formLogin().and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Added the code in SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth class  and also updated the  cross origin as @CrossOrigin(origins="*") but still getting the error

Comment: OPTIONS API is getting pass with 200 status code  but getting one more request-Request URL: http://localhost:8080/hello/variable/paraan 
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: for Referrer Policy , look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) it might help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221384/discussion-between-thakur-amit-and-harry).

Comment: still getting cors error not working

Comment: Now zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET http://localhost:8080 /hello/variable/paraan net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED is coming after adding SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) in SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth.java

Comment: `.and().headers().referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicy.NO_REFERRER);` add this into configure and remove the earlier code. import from `org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy`

Comment: I added the .cors() in SpringSecurityConfigurationBasicAuth.java. Now I am not getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin error but  getting core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of null error

Comment: Code is working fine and there is no CORS or ERR_Failed error coming but OPTIONS API is not getting called only GET API is called. If there is spring security then OPTION should be called then GET API. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `CORS` support with `CrossOrigin` annotation or with Java config.

For more information visit this link:

[CORS support in Spring Framework](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

> You can add to your @RequestMapping annotated handler method a
> @CrossOrigin annotation in order to enable CORS on it (by default
> @CrossOrigin allows all origins and the HTTP methods specified in the
> @RequestMapping annotation):

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> It is also possible to enable CORS for the whole controller:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://domain2.com", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already enable it in my RestController class but still getting error-@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")

Comment: You error is because of the CORS. Try this: change it to `@CrossOrigin(origins="*")`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CorsFilter bean

```
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this into your code.

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.headers()
        .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicy.NO_REFERRER);
    return http.build();
}
```